# How to search for nested values in Resources(tastypie json)

Tags: python, json, django, tastypie, jsonresponse

Hi I have the following resources inside respurces.py file.

```
class SodResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Sod.objects.all().order_by('-rank')
        filtering = {'sod_type': ALL, 'generic_value': ALL}


class DeptBpResource(ModelResource):
    sod_setting = fields.ToManyField(SodResource, 'sod',  null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Dept_Bp.objects.all()
        filtering = {
                'dept_name': ALL,
                'bp_name': ALL,
            }
```

I can able to search `http://10.85.87.116:8000/fmea/api/v1/deptbp/?format=json&dept_name=DEQP&bp_name=Kaizen`. But my aim is to able to search the `sod_type` also (Which is from the above resource). But when I search as `http://10.85.87.116:8000/fmea/api/v1/deptbp/?format=json&dept_name=DEQP&bp_name=Kaizen&sod_type=1` Its just returning the same value as `http://10.85.87.116:8000/fmea/api/v1/deptbp/?format=json&dept_name=DEQP&bp_name=Kaizen` not narrowing down my search. Am bit new to resources or tastypie. What's wrong here guys? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class SodResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Sod.objects.all().order_by('-rank')
        filtering = {'sod_type': ALL, 'generic_value': ALL}


class DeptBpResource(ModelResource):
    sod_setting = fields.ToManyField(SodResource, 'sod',  null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Dept_Bp.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            'dept_name': ALL,
            'bp_name': ALL,
            'sod_setting': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

On your url. You can do like this:

```
http://10.85.87.116:8000/fmea/api/v1/deptbp/?format=json&dept_name=DEQP&bp_name=Kaizen&sod_setting__type=1
```